# Running a php script with a .bat file

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I need to run a php script at midnight every night on my server. On a linux system I'd set up a cron job, but I'm stuck with a windows system.

I know I have to set up a task using the windows task scheduler, and that the task will need to run a .bat file which in turn will run the php file, but I'm stuck trying to write the .bat file.

What I currently have is:

```
@echo off
REM this command runs the nightly cron job
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\crons\reminder-email.php
```

But when I try to manually run the .bat file to test it, I get a windows alert saying

> "Windows cannot find '-f'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `START` command optionally accepts a title for the created window as its first argument; in this case, it thinks that `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe` is the title to display and `-f` (the second argument) is the executable you want to run.

You can therefore fix this by providing a placeholder title, e.g.

```
start "email reminder task" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\crons\reminder-email.php
```

Or, preferably, you can ditch the `START` command altogether (you aren't using any of its unique facilities) and just run PHP directly:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\crons\reminder-email.php
```

Comment: just one problem, bat don't wait until the script ends

Comment: @a77icu5: Well, it was not a problem in the context of the question, and anyway it only happens if you use `START` (invoking directly waits until PHP executing ends). Even with `START`, you can use `/WAIT` to match the direct invocation behavior.

Comment: How do I let the cmd window to remain open? let say i'm running a script for web socket indefinitely.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you don't even need a batch-file.
You can run the php-script from the task scheduler.

Just let the task scheduler run php.exe and set the location of the php-file as the argument of the task.

Comment: worked perfectly. pretty obvious answer as well.  not sure why I didn't just try this in the first place!

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Good Idea!

Answer (score 3):

Can I suggest a small change.

```
echo off
REM This adds the folder containing php.exe to the path
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3

REM Change Directory to the folder containing your script
CD C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\crons

REM Execute
php reminder-email.php
```

PS. Putting Apache,MySQL or PHP in `Program Files` is a bad idea. Dont use windows folders with spaces in their names.

Comment: I 'm not sure why one would choose to do things this way. For example, why CD to the cron script directory? Why add something to the PATH instead of just specifying the path in the command line? And finally, what's the problem with putting things in Program Files? I 've been doing it for years; as long as you properly quote the directory name whenever needed things of course work just fine.

Comment: I'm working with a pre-existing system, so the file structure is out of my hands.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
set php="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe"
%php% -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\crons\reminder-email.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this took close to 10 hours to figure out. Some protocols such as WinRM and PSEXEC must pass the logged in user account regardless of the credentials supplied (that or PHP overrides whatever you type in). At any rate, to get PSEXEC, WinRM or just kicking off batch files that connect to remote computers, you will need to change the IIS run as account to a user with rights to those resources (service account). I realize this is a huge security hole, but that is by design. PHP is secure so that it can't be hacked easily, you have to override their security by specifying a run as account. Not the same thing as your app pool account - although your IIS credentials can use your app pool account.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this guys!

```
cd E:\xampp\htdocs\my-project
E:
php artisan schedule:run
```