# how to echo "<?php" into a file from a .BAT

Tags: php, batch-file, echo

I know there is probably a better way of doing this, but I am unaware of how to do it...

I am wanting to add

```
<?php
```

into a file, I currently have a bat file with this line

```
echo <?php >> config.php
```

But it complains about syntax when I run the bat file, I have played around with it as much as I can work out, but I can't get the

I really hope someone can help me

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a php script with a .bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488946/running-a-php-script-with-a-bat-file)

Comment: I'm not wanting to run php from that bat, but echo the new line into my existing file via a bat file, sorry, I just noticed it has removed some of my script, i will see if i can fix it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `^` escape character to treat `<` as a literal string and not a redirection operator.

```
echo ^<?php >>config.php
```

Comment: You absolute legend :)